# Ordering markers according to time posted

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I put together a Wordpress plugin Twitchers that allows people to post wildlife sightings etc through a website. You can download it free from Wordpress ( a bit of promo :) )

I'm currently using it to let people report rhino poaching incidents http://wildlifenews.co.uk/tell-the-world-the-rhino-are-dying/

I have set the markers to display a different colour depending on how long ago the report was published. The issue I have is trying to get the markers of the most recent report to display higher than the older reports.

I'm not sure why but older reports can sometimes swamp and hide the newest reports depending on the zoom level.

What's the best way to bring the most recent reports to the front? I've tried to inject div styles and z-index into the code but it does not work.

Any suggests as to the route to explore?

thanks
Kevin

Comment: You should post the code you've written if you're expecting help ;)

Comment: Hi AlexB thanks for the comment. I'll remeber next time. Sorry i did not reply earluer but i did not notice the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use markers [**`zIndex`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) for that. Like in CSS, a higher zIndex gives higher internal "rank". Cannot totally comprehend your code (seems to be repetetive javascript generated serverside?) but you have `days` and a function `addMarker`.

Pass days to that addMarker function :

```js
var addMarker = function(map, latlng, days) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        position: latlng,
        zIndex: daysToIndex(days), //set zIndex here
        icon: image
    });
    return marker;
};
```

function daysToIndex could be something like

```js
function daysToIndex(days) {
    if (parseInt(days)<5) {
        return 10;
    }
    if (parseInt(days)<25) {
        return 9;
    }
    if (parseInt(days)<50) {
        return 8;
    }
    //..
    //etc
}
```

Comment: Hey @user3009382, thank you. And welcome to stackoverflow. But you do not have to accept an answer you have not tried out yet. Only when you feel an answer fullfill your needs, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Hi I had to do a bit of adaption but it works. I did not need the function and just added the daysToIndex = 3; etc to the conditional statement used to choose the marker colour. That was then fed into the zindex variable. The plugin is probably not coded the best as I'm self-taught but if it works... fortunately my coding does not pay my wages :)

Comment: @user3009382, sounds great! And I like your project. Save the rhinos. In the future, if you have problems, try change the value of optimized. But in general I had not discovered problems with this approach, and I have pages with more than 10.000 markers ordered by their date (biological / environmental issues also)